# Which of the following planes is perpendicular to $(1+2t,4t,3-2t)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, plane-geometry

$$(x,y,z)=(1+2t,4t,3-2t),t\in\Bbb R$$
A) $2x - y - z = 5$

B) $2x + 6z = 1$

C) $2x - y = -3$

D) $-3x -6y + 3z = 2$

Which one is it and why??

Comment: Hi, Nicolas, welcome to Math.SE! Please update your question with what your thoughts on the problem are and we will be glad to help you with guidance. People here are usually not fond of doing your homework for you...

Comment: my bad, did not know i had to put my research on this issue first, first time posting here, will do next time

Comment: Mayeb do it *this* time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the trick is here to prove that the normal vector of the given plane and the direction vector of the straight line are linear depending.
For A) $$2x-y-z=5$$ then we have $$\vec{n}=[2;-1;-1]$$ and $$\vec{a}=[2;4;-2]$$ then you will get $$\vec{n}\ne \lambda\vec{a}$$
and for D we get
$$2=-3t$$
$$4=-6t$$
$$-2=-3t$$ thus $$t=-\frac{2}{3}$$ they are orthogonal